# Transfering momentum to angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws

What if you had an isolated system with a rotating and a stationary object in which the rotating body pushes the stationary one and therefore transfers some of its angular momentum into the linear motion and therefore momentum. Individually, angular and linear momentum aren't conserved. Does this violate the law of conservation of momentum and law of conservation of angular momentum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Individually, angular and linear momentum aren't conserved.

No, they are.

First, the system's initial linear momentum is **not zero**, by $L=rp$, we know it's initial linear momentum is $p=\frac{L}{r}$. After their interaction, some of them are transferred to the stationary object.

Also, for the stationary object, which is now moving along a straight line, it has a linear momentum $p_s$. Again, by $L=rp$, it can have angular momentum, too. r is the distance between the object to the rotation axis of the rotating object.

To conclude, an important concept to realize this question is that having linear momentum and angular momentum isn't determined by if it's rotating or translating. Instead, **every moving object** have a linear momentum, defined by $p=mv$, and **every moving object with a given axis** can have a angular momentum , defined by $L=rp$. Thus, there's no such a thing called "Transferring momentum to angular momentum".

I hope that this is helpful!

Comment: I see now, thank you